# Holding onto the head of sequence when using "rest"

Tags: clojure

I am parsing a big csv file and I am using the first line of it as the keys for the records. So for a csv file like:

```
header1,header2
foo,bar
zoo,zip
```

I end up with a lazy seq like:

```
({:header1 "foo" :header2 "bar"},
 {:header1 "zoo" :header2 "zip"})
```

The code working fine, but I am not sure if in the following function I am holding the head of "lines" or not.

```
(defn csv-as-seq [file]
  (let [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
    (let [lines (line-seq rdr)
         headers (parse-headers (first lines))]
      (map (row-mapper headers) (rest lines)))))
```

Can somebody please clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by holding onto head? Did you test the code? Does it yield the expected output?

Comment: @missingfaktor: I think what he means is, since lines is in scope for the duration of map, is it holding onto the sequence consumed by map so that none of the sequence ever gets GCed until lines goes out of scope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this expression syntactically says to hold the head

```
(let [lines (line-seq rdr)
```

though in this case you should get away with it because their are no references to 
`lines` and `headers` after the call to map and the Clojure compiler starting with 1.2.x includes a feature called **locals clearing**: it sets any locals not used after a function call to nil in the preamble to the function call. In this case it will set lines and headers to nil in the local context of the function and they will be GCd as used. This is one of the rare cases where clojure produces bytecode that cannot be expressed in java.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure I have the starting version for this feature correct, anyone know for sure?

Comment: Arthur you are right. I have test the function with a csv file with several million rows on a JVM with 64Mb of Xmx and it hasn't run out of memory.

Comment: Bytecode that cannot be expressed in java? It's easily expressed in clojure.lang.Util/ret1. You just have a method that takes two arguments and returns the first one. Then you make the second arg you pass it have the side effect of nulling out your reference. So something like: `f.invoke(Util.ret1(x, x = null));`.

Comment: Arthur, what in OP's code were you referring to by "not used after a function call"?  Do you mean that `lines` is set to `nil` once it's handed off to `rest`?  (Sorry to ask question about an old answer, but it's one that's obviously still relevant and important.)

Comment: @Mars Yes that is correct. it takes the local "variable" where lines was being kept and after putting the value from it onto the call stack sets the location where it had been kept to nil.

Comment: Thanks Arthur.  I'm trying to track down an apparent held head bug.  That rules out some sources.